# prestashop web services not working with rest client

Tags: php, rest, prestashop

I want to consume PrestaShop web services with REST client. I used Chrome [Advanced rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

My request URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8090/prestashop/api/customers`.

Headers are `u: V7846EKZZJ1OJAW486D66IS7GO24XKUZ`.

I am always redirecting to the PrestaShop home page with this request. If I erase htaccess file then I am getting 404 page not found error.
I have enabled the web services with PrestaShop admin > advanced parameters > web services.
There I enabled both "PrestaShop's webservice" and "Active mode CGI for PHP" and I also generated the above mentioned key and enabled it.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution.
I haven't enabled CURL for PHP. After enabling that I can access web services.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a workaround:

> http://127.0.0.1:8090/prestashop/webservice/dispatcher.php?url=customers

It seems that URL rewriting needs to be enabled.